# Continually Running Web Application

Tags: php, web-applications

I am creating a reminder system which uses sms messages to send event reminders from a database.  I plan to create the site using php to produce forms and handle database access.
One feature that i need is the ability to send the reminders automatically (so for example at 12pm every day), without the user being logged into the site, which is what i am stuck on.
Is there a simple way to do this? I have searched google without much luck.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, that looks like exactly what i need.

Comment: If you find a response helpful, you should accept the answer!

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I have used this site to ask a question. Answer now accepted.

Comment: No need for an apology, just a community reminder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup a cronjob on your server to do that. Check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) link for example. So, basically, your cronjob will execute some PHP script which will access the database and perform all the actions.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like a job for cron. http://learn.clemsonlinux.org/wiki/Cron